# Is it possible to include a Box Collider component into a Raw Image game object to detect collisions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

A raw image seems intended only for UI. However it seems UI objects (panel or canvas) cannot include a collider.

The opposite solution I have try is to use a 3d panel, but I don't know how to convert a Raw Image (png file) into a Material. Is it any other way to show a png image in a Plane game object?

I want to include a piece of code like:

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
{
    // TODO called when the game object that includes this script is collided 
    //      (if it has a Collider component with isTrigger enabled)
}
```

My workaround so far is using a 3d game object with a collider and a separated UI game object with the raw image. It seems a botch for me, but maybe it is the best solution!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible but the collider is not meant to be used with the UI components.

If you want to do this change  the Canvas Render Mode to World Space:

[image]

Then manually Modify the Collider to fit the RawImage. Give it a depth too so that it is not flat:

[image]

---

If you decide to use 3D object then [VTodorov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46689095/3785314)'s answer should do it.

With a simple plane you can do that from script:

```
public Texture2D yourTeture;
public GameObject plane;

void Start()
{
    MeshRenderer meshRenderer = plane.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    meshRenderer.material.mainTexture = yourTeture;
}
```

Comment: Note: any time the canvas asks for an event camera *always assign it.* World Space canvases don't require this field to be assigned (unlike a Camera Space canvas) but this just means that it calls `Camera.main` which internally uses `GameObject.FindObjectWithTag("MainCamera")` *and is not cached.* And we all know how lag-inducing `GameObject.Find` is...

Comment: @Draco18s I didn't know about this.

Comment: I didn't either until I ran into a talk on YouTube from a Unity guy talking about it. Let me see... was either [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-oZa4Fb12U) or [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_wxitgdx-UI). Both are worth watching.

Comment: The canvas way seems easier to me. Do you recommend the 3D object solution in some cases? Thank you this is s very well explained answer :)

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing. If you can explain what you are doing, I will tell you which one is proper for this.

Comment: @Programmer a bike will collide with objects. Depending on the image of the object, the moto will get special capacities.

Comment: What does the object look like?

Comment: @Programmer the moto is a cuboid. The moto impacts against raw images.

Answer (score 1):

You can create materials in Unity pretty easy. Just import your image into Unity then click Assets -> Create -> Material. Select your material and drag your image to your inspector (there should be a field called  "None (Texture 2D)" or something like that). Then you can apply your material to any object you want.

Comment: Thank you. I did not it was so easy. I'd need to do it in runtime though. I'd need to do it in a script: I guess it is possible too!